# Replacing leading text in Python

Tags: python, string

I use Python 2.6 and I want to replace each instance of certain leading characters (`.`, `_` and `$` in my case) in a string with another character or string. Since in my case the replacement string is the same, I came up with this:

```
def replaceLeadingCharacters(string, old, new = ''):
    t = string.lstrip(old)

    return new * (len(string) - len(t)) + t
```

which seems to work fine:

```
>>> replaceLeadingCharacters('._.!$XXX$._', '._$', 'Y')
'YYY!$XXX$._'
```

- Is there a better (simpler or more efficient) way to achieve the same effect in Python ?
- Is there a way to achieve this effect with a string instead of characters? Something like str.replace() that stops once something different than the string-to-be-replaced comes up in the input string? Right now I've come up with this:

  ```
  def replaceLeadingString(string, old, new = ''):
      n = 0
      o = 0
      s = len(old)

      while string.startswith(old, o):
          n += 1
          o += s

      return new * n + string[o:]
  ```

  I am hoping that there is a way to do this without an explicit loop

EDIT:

There are quite a few answers using the `re` module. I have a couple of questions/issues with it:

- Isn't it significantly slower than the `str` methods when used as a replacement for them?
- Is there an easy way to properly quote/escape strings that will be used in a regular expression? For example if I wanted to use `re` for `replaceLeadingCharacters`, how would I ensure that the contents of the `old` variable will not mess things up in `^[old]+` ? I'd rather have a "black-box" function that does not require its users to pay attention to the list of characters that they provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `replaceLeadingCharacters()` seems fine as is.

Here's `replaceLeadingString()` implementation that uses [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) module (without the `while` loop):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

def lreplace(s, old, new):
    """Return a copy of string `s` with leading occurrences of
    substring `old` replaced by `new`.

    >>> lreplace('abcabcdefabc', 'abc', 'X')
    'XXdefabc'
    >>> lreplace('_abc', 'abc', 'X')
    '_abc'
    """
    return re.sub(r'^(?:%s)+' % re.escape(old),
                  lambda m: new * (m.end() / len(old)),
                  s)
```

> Isn't it significantly slower than the str methods when used as a replacement for them?

Don't guess. Measure it for expected input.

> Is there an easy way to properly quote/escape strings that will be used in a regular expression?

[`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape)

Comment: Nice and useful! I totally missed `re.escape()` in the `re` documentation. +1

Comment: Well, on my system `timeit` says your `lreplace()` function is significantly faster than my own for any string larger than 50 characters. Very nice!

Comment: @thkala: if you paste your code (e.g. on http://ideone.com/ or as an answer here) I could test it on my machine.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I compared with the `replaceLeadingString()` function from my question - I have not come up with something better.

Comment: @thkala: I've meant what kind of input data you expect: string length distribution, "number of times input string starts with old" distribution (or just averages). For example, for short strings `replaceLeadingString()` is `8` times faster than `lreplace()` http://ideone.com/A53co

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I don't have any concrete data at the moment, but a bit of benchmarking is in order once I do. It might even be possible to use some kind of hybrid approach...

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub(r'^[._$]+', lambda m: 'Y' * m.end(0), '._.!$XXX$._')
```

But IMHO your first solution is good enough.

Comment: This is an interesting alternative, although `timeit` says it is significantly slower that the `str`-based version for short strings. It gets faster as the input string grows, though, so it might catch up for larger strings.